# Correct Usage of URLs in WordPress Stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, url, wordpress-theming

I've been researching a lot about the advantages / disadvantages of using relative vs. absolute paths for images in my CSS. After reading [this discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-relative-instead-of-absolute-links-for-images) I'm starting to think absolute is what I should be using. I'm not worried at all about the cross-domain compatibility issue. My main concern is weight of my site. Will putting in all of these absolute URLs in my style sheet create a bunch of server requests? Or is there some other way that using absolute will bog down the site?

I'd also like to know what the correct way to make absolute paths is in WordPress Stylesheets. Isn't there some kind of structure that they prefer? I know CSS files don't typically parse php so using something like `background-image: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/background.jpg);`is not correct but is there a way that they prefer to have the absolute URLs structured? I've checked the [WordPress CSS Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/css/) but they gave little information on images and URLs. I think there was only one example and notably it's a relative path...

Please help me understand the correct way to handle URLs in a WordPress Stylesheet. Any information and references you have are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the full url in your css file. If you ever move the files to a new domain, you'll have a lot of cleaning up to do. Relative paths are fine as long as your not changing your directory structure.

```
background: url("../images/background.jpg");
```

I don't know of any official best practices for Wordpress on this matter, but I'm sure you'll be fine sticking to whatever works best for you.